Camunda 8 - Authentication Issue occurred while fetching the Task from the Tasklist API
We are currently progressing to integrate the Camunda User Task completion from Spring Boot application. We have referred the below link for our integration.
https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-tools/tasklist-api-rest/tasklist-api-rest-tutorial/#generate-the-tasklist-api-client
But unfortunately, we are facing some Authentication issues.
Configurations setup in local machine:
application.properties:
camunda.client.mode=simple
camunda.client.auth.username=demo
camunda.client.auth.password=demo
camunda.client.zeebe.enabled=true
camunda.client.zeebe.gateway-url=http://localhost:26500/
camunda.client.zeebe.base-url=http://localhost:8080/
camunda.client.zeebe.prefer-rest-over-grpc=false
camunda.client.operate.enabled=true
camunda.client.operate.base-url=http://localhost:8081
camunda.client.tasklist.enabled=true
camunda.client.tasklist.base-url=http://localhost:8082/```

Error:
ERROR 26824 — [demo] [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to authenticate
at io.camunda.common.auth.SimpleAuthentication.retrieveToken(SimpleAuthentication.java:58) ~[java-common-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
at io.camunda.common.auth.SimpleAuthentication.getTokenHeader(SimpleAuthentication.java:79) ~[java-common-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
at io.camunda.common.http.DefaultHttpClient.retrieveToken(DefaultHttpClient.java:207) ~[java-common-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
at io.camunda.common.http.DefaultHttpClient.post(DefaultHttpClient.java:148) ~[java-common-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
at io.camunda.operate.CamundaOperateClient.searchProcessDefinitionResults(CamundaOperateClient.java:46) ~[java-client-operate-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
at io.camunda.operate.CamundaOperateClient.searchProcessDefinitions(CamundaOperateClient.java:41) ~[java-client-operate-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to authenticate due to missing Set-Cookie
at io.camunda.common.auth.SimpleAuthentication.retrieveToken(SimpleAuthentication.java:53) ~[java-common-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
… 26 common frames omitted


Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks.
We need to integrate user access and task management functionality into a Spring Boot application. This includes features for users to access their tasks and mark them as completed.

Are you using Self-Managed or SaaS? Do you have Identity enabled? Have you googled the error message Unable to authenticate due to missing Set-Cookie?

we are using "Self-Managed", Identity already enabled
